# How do I fetch lines in a log file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

The program I wrote prints the data in the log file to the GUI. It performs filtering operations by selecting some features. I'm fetching data line by line
I can fetch the line with the words according to the date and time format.

But what I want is to fetch the lines above the lines I want.
When I type 5 in the Entry, I want the word I want to search to be taken 5 lines above.

For example, my word is 'Timer'. When I write Timer in the entry and I select the before lines checkbox and write 5 in the before line entry. I want to take this;

```
[01/01/70 02:00:18.699984 ] [debug  ] [1403] [DmTr069EventHandler.c:55] [dmTr069EventHandler_init] LEAVED 
[01/01/70 02:00:18.700122 ] [debug  ] [1403] [DmUkaEventHandler.c:50] [dmUkaEventHandler_init] ENTERED 
[01/01/70 02:00:18.700143 ] [debug  ] [1403] [DmUkaEventHandler.c:52] [dmUkaEventHandler_init] LEAVED 
[01/01/70 02:00:18.700154 ] [debug  ] [1403] [DmAppEventHandler.c:81] [dmAppEventHandler_init] ENTERED 
[01/01/70 02:00:18.700237 ] [debug  ] [1403] [Timer.c:441] [addTimerToSortedTimerList] ENTERED
```

The code is here. I tried something but it didn't work for beforeline feature.

```
def search(msg, startingDate, endingDate, beforeLine, varBefore):
# clear current result
text.delete('1.0', 'end')
with open('OAM.log', 'r', encoding='latin1') as fp:
    global l_no
    for l_no, line in enumerate(fp, 1):
        if msg and msg not in line:
            # does not contain search message, skip it
            continue
        if startingDate or endingDate:
            # get the timestamp
            timestamp = parse_date(line[1:25])
            # within startingDate and endingDate ?
            if startingDate and timestamp < startingDate:
                # before given starting date, skip it
                continue
            if endingDate and timestamp > endingDate:
                # after given ending date, skip it
                continue

        """for count, beforeLine in enumerate(fp, 1):
            #bfline = fp.readlines(l_no - count)
            count -= 1
            text.insert('end', ' \n ')
            text.insert('end', f'Before Line Number: {l_no - beforeEntryVar.get()} Log: {beforeLine}')
            text.insert('end', ' \n ')"""
            
        # insert the log
        text.insert('end', ' \n ')
        text.insert('end', f'Line Number: {l_no} Log: {line}')
        text.insert('end', ' \n ')
```

Comment: Are you saying that with the sample data you want to get the first line because the 5th line contains Timer? What would you do if Timer occurred, for example, in line 3 of the file - i.e., there are fewer than 5 lines preceding it?

Comment: Actually, it's like this, if the row with the word is the 5th, I want it to fetch the 4 rows above it. So 5-4-3-2-1. If there are no 5 rows in front of them, then how many rows have to come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with a deque as follows:

```
import re
from collections import deque

def read_logfile(filename, key, maxlines):
    p = r'(?<=\[).+?(?=\])'
    d = deque([], maxlines)
    with open(filename) as log:
        for line in map(str.strip, log):
            d.append(line)
            if len(m := re.findall(p, line)) > 3 and m[3].startswith(key):
                return d
    return []

print(*read_logfile('OAM.log', 'Timer', 5), sep='\n')
```

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: @Matthew I tested with your sample data. In what way did it not work for you?

Comment: I gave the word 'timer' as an example. This is something that is constantly changing. I get this data from the user via Tkinter entry. I also get the number 5 from the user. It won't always be the same number

Comment: @Matthew OK - So wrap the logic in a function and pass the keyword ('Timer' or whatever) and line count (5) as parameters